GLMM for not so gaussian data
I am having an issue with GLMM and hope you could advice me.
So basically I have data from microscopy experiment of three independent groups (variable: subfolder) nested within 4 experimental replicates (variable: file_name): bunch of cells were measured together in 4 individual experiments.
Graph below shows values for three experimental groups, color of each measurement represents each experiment.
I want to compare differences between experimental groups (I know in this case is pretty obvious). So I use GLMM from glmmTMB to model this dataset: m <- glmmTMB(mean_new_deltaR ~ subfolder+(1 | file_name), dispformula=~ subfolder, data=mean_deltaR) and would use emmeans afterwards. Because variance is sure not even between groups I model using dispformula. However, when I do diagnostics using DHAMRa, residuals dont look great. What would be sincere way about it? Would robust GLM be an option?


Hi @Julius, welcome to CV. What is the actual thing you are measuring? What are you trying to determine from the experiment?

Sometimes, if you have positive only data with some skew, maybe a Gamma distribution would be more appropriate than Gaussian. What's the plot on the left?
Tbh, looking at what you've got, it's not a perfect DHARMa residual but it doesn't look too bad... this is real life data after all!

Thank you so much for prompt response! So basically I am measuring response of cells to three different compounds. As I do it under microscope, I record response from numerous cells at once. To be sure about robustness of my measurements I repeat experiments. Now I want to compare responses between compounds, taking into consideration correlated nature of responses from individual experiments. The ultimate goal is to do pairwise comparisons.

The plot on the left represents my data structure: columns- different compounds tested, small dots- individual response values from a single cell, bigger dots-average of individual experiments, same color-for same experiment. I was actually thinking about Gamma- but some values are unfortunately negative :(. At the moment I  am thinking of coming up with a justified way to filter off values in tails of distribution to make it more gaussian or go with robustlmm.

(sorry for the late response) - tbh, I think what you have got already looks fine. Try a robust version if you want, but I am never too fussed by residuals not looking textbook.

Thank you! That is very encouraging. Will stay away from robust statistical methods at the moment.
